# C++ library to read a document, created within "Open Office Calc"

Tags: openoffice-calc, odf

I have the file created within "Open Office Calc" which I need to load into my C++ program to generate some game-specific code for which this design file was written. All I need is spreadsheets names, fields data and formulas results.

Is there a way to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: All OpenOffice files are zip-archives, with the contents in publicly specified XML files. Might be some work but would not be impossible to get the data you need with the help of most available XML-parsers.

Comment: At first I thought such solution too complicated but after hours spent with OpenOfficeSDK which runs **calc** executable, creates some **pdb** and **registry** files (along with it's weird **hpp** sources generated from **hxx**), uses socket connection and installed OpenOffice version on target PC has to be the same as SDK version with which program was compiled. Can you post the same as answer so I could accept it? Thank you.

Comment: I used minizip to unzip **ods** file and pugixml to read xml data (Office writes formula results into output XML too). There are just 400 lines of code. Don't think it even worth to share with somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All OpenOffice files are zip-archives, with the contents in publicly specified XML files. Might be some work but would not be impossible to get the data you need with the help of most available XML-parsers.